# Xcode Unable to change second childViewController's frame

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a `MenuViewController` and inside this `viewController` I have two childViewControllers which first one is on left part and second one is on the right side.

```
VIEW_WIDTH = self.view.frame.size.width;
WIDTH_ListTableView = 0.4;

ListViewController *listViewController  = [[ListViewController alloc] init];
ListNavigationViewController *listViewNavigation = [[ListNavigationViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:listViewController];
[self addChildViewController:listViewNavigation];
[self.view insertSubview:listViewNavigation.view belowSubview:self.searchBarView.view];
[listViewNavigation didMoveToParentViewController:self];
listViewNavigation.view.frame   = CGRectMake(0,
                                             y,
                                             VIEW_WIDTH*WIDTH_ListTableView,
                                             height);






PreViewViewController *readViewController = [[PreViewViewController alloc] init];
[self addChildViewController:readViewController];
[self.view insertSubview:readViewController.view belowSubview:listViewNavigation.view];
[readViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
readViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(listViewNavigation.view.frame.origin.x + listViewNavigation.view.frame.size.width,
                                           listViewNavigation.view.frame.origin.y,
                                           VIEW_WIDTH - listViewNavigation.view.frame.size.width,
                                           listViewNavigation.view.frame.size.height);
```

But I cannot change the frame of `readViewController` and its width and height are always **(768.0, 1024.0)**.

I added constraint to listViewNavigation, but **listViewNavigation.view.y = 0**

```
- (void)addConstraintWithListNavigationViewController:(UIView *)listViewNavigation y:(CGFloat)y height:(CGFloat)height
{
    //set x = 0;
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraintToAnimate1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:listViewNavigation
                                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                               toItem:self.view
                                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                           multiplier:0.00
                                                                             constant:0];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraintToAnimate1];


    //set y = y;
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraintToAnimate2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:listViewNavigation
                                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                               toItem:self.view
                                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                           multiplier:0.00
                                                                             constant:y];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraintToAnimate2];








    //set Width = self.view.frame.size.width*0.4
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraintToAnimate3 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:listViewNavigation
                                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                               toItem:self.view
                                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                           multiplier:WIDTH_ListTableView
                                                                             constant:0.0];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraintToAnimate3];





    //Set height = height
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraintToAnimate4 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:listViewNavigation
                                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                               toItem:nil
                                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                           multiplier:0.00
                                                                             constant:height];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraintToAnimate4];
}
```

Comment: `[self.view updateConstraints];` or `[self.view updateConstraintsIfNeeded];` ??

Comment: This two make the layout too bad.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are have auto layout enabled. Try to update the constraints after changing frame by using the function [readViewController.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES]

Comment: I posted my Code for adding Constraint, but always get listViewNavigation.view.y = 0.